# Six's socket implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, python-2.x, six

I build an app compatible between Python 2 and 3. In order to provide compatibility between those two Python versions, I use [six library](https://pythonhosted.org/six/).

My code uses [sockets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket). Under Python 3 it is possible to create them using `with` statement, but under Python 2 it claims on missing `__exit__` attribute.

Is there any function of six providing disposable socket? If not, what solution would you consider as the most clear in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK (by scanning through its docs) `six` doesn't do much in this case. In Python 2, you could wrap `socket` up in a context manager with the `contextmanager` decorator and supply that:

```
from sys import version_info 
import socket

if version_info[0] == 2:
    from contextlib import contextmanager

    @contextmanager
    def sock(*args, **kwargs):
        s = socket.socket(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            yield s
        finally:
            s.close()
else:  # Python 3
    sock = socket.socket
```

In both cases you use the `with` statement accordingly:

```
with sock(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    # use s
```

Comment: good point. the only change I would apply in comparison to your suggestion is using six Python version checking (https://pythonhosted.org/six/#package-contents) instead of `version_info[0]`.

Comment: Additional question: what is the benefit of introducing two versions instead of using python2 version only?

Comment: @pt12lol yes, I missed the try-finally. I'm guessing you could rebind the name `socket` to the context manager version in Python 2 but I don't like renaming standard names like that. Instead, I opted to bind it to a new name which you can use unconditionally.